# Global declared in a class function is not available in included file?

Tags: php, global-variables

Take the following php class:

```
 class test
 {
    function do_it_to_it(){
        global $path;

        if(somecondition){
           $path = 'path/to/goodies';
           require_once('some_file');
        }
    }
 }
```

The contents of "some_file" are as follows:

```
global $path;
define('GOODIEPATH', $path);
```

Now I call:

```
$t1 = new test();
$t1->do_it_to_it();
```

$path in "some_file" will be null instead of "path/to/goodies."  I have a feeling that this is because $path is either being overwritten for some reason by the second "global $path" or because of some type of global scope issue.  What am I missing here?

P.S. - I hate globals more than anybody, but I can't fix it in this case without breaking legacy code.

**EDIT**:  I have revised the `test` class above to show an `if` statement that is present in the real code.  I seem to have resolved the issue by moving the `global` statement inside the `if` statement, like so:

```
class test
{
   function do_it_to_it(){

     if(somecondition){
        global $path;
        $path = 'path/to/goodies';
        require_once('some_file');
     }
   }
}
```

Any idea why this seems to fix it?  The `if` statement causes the original `global` declaration to be out of scope somehow?

Comment: +1 for hating globals but being stuck with legacy code.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `global $path;` in the contents of `"some_file"`. In fact, you should be able to do this without both `global` statements - Included files are executed within the scope that they're included, and you set a value for `$path` right before you include the file that tries to read `$path`.

Comment: And the question is? You want to refactor? Or want a fix for `class Test`?

Comment: Just tested this code and it works as expected; `$path` has a proper value inside the `some_file`

Comment: works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/coxo5L and http://codepad.viper-7.com/Wp6ly1

Comment: @Gordon OP mentioned that `$path` had no value _inside_ the included file; don't think your pastie qualifies :)

Comment: @Jack well, since I can echo the constant defined in http://codepad.viper-7.com/Wp6ly1 in http://codepad.viper-7.com/coxo5L I dont see why it shouldn't qualify. It's the same setup the OP has. The constant wouldn't get set if $path was null.

Comment: @nickb, I should have mentioned I can't change "some_file" as it will break legacy code.  I am writing the "test" class, so I can do as I please with it.

Comment: @JvdBerg, I'm just trying to understand what happens in this case.  But yes, I ultimately want to fix class Test.

Comment: @Gordon, Jack thanks for verifying it works for you.  I suppose it could be something else causing the problem.  Its odd because as I step through the code using xdebug/NetBeans, I can see the value of $path set correctly on the first line of "some_file" but as soon as I step to the next line it is null.

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend to define global variables on the zero level of the code for example in separate file and include this file in all sources.